# Random.Range and how to getRandom

Tags: c#, algorithm

[image]

These 9 balls are generated randomly according to the code below.

```
   for(int i=0;i<balls.Length; i++)
    {
        getBallsRandom = new Randomizer(balls[i].sprites);
        balls[i].setCurrentSpriteIndex(getBallsRandom.getRandom());
    }
```

All I want is that every time you generate 3 balls of each color. For example in the image below.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the current implementation? The colors appear to be randomly assorted.

Comment: I don't see the crucial difference between two images. Can you explain further?

Comment: They appear random but it is necessary for the red balloon to appear 3 times, the green 3 times and the white 3 times. Like in the second picture.

Comment: Look for [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: It appears that in the first picture the green balloon is repeated 4 times, but it must be 3 times

Comment: It would be nice to edit your post in order to clarify it.

Comment: @coincoin: It does say "All I want is that every time you generate 3 balls of each color." which seems pretty clear to me...

Comment: Well, I apologize for my English

Comment: You just wrote to correct me on the grammar or you got the answer

Comment: I think it's nice now. @George I have understood also but the edited post is much clearer !

Answer (score 2):

Make a list of your balls `list_balls = [Green, Green, Green, Red, Red, Red, Grey, Grey, Grey]`.

Here the idea in pseudocode:

```
for i=1 to 3: // for each tube
  for j=1 to 3: // 3 balls in each tube
    Pick a random ball from `list_balls`
    Remove the chosen ball from `list_balls`
```

I let you the pleasure to write that in C#